# Detecting Not-A-Number (NAN) or +-infinity in Access and Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, nan

Oracle provides functions to test whether a stored value is NaN or +-infinity.  Is there something similar that can be used in Access and Sql Server?

Comment: Sql server doesn't currently support those https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/239674/storing-ieee-754-floats-in-sql-server-2005-nan-infinity. You'd need to create a custom CLR datatype and use the CLR implementation of floating point.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Access can detect "NaN" and "+/-Infinity", at least for values that reside in `Double` columns of a native Access table:

[image: DatasheetView.png]

You can even have Access perform queries like the following, which will return all rows that contain a "NaN" (positive or negative) in the `Double` column:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Right(CStr([DoubleField]), 3) = 'NAN';
```

However, support for those special values could very well be incomplete. For example, I'm not aware of a way to insert or update those values (e.g., `CDbl("1.#INF")` does not work.)

Comment: Well, Right(CStr([DoubleField]), 3)  returns 'IND' in my environment (from "-1.#IND"), i.e. when querying by Jet.OLEDB from a 3-d party tool. So it makes sense to take this into account when checking in runtime.

Comment: When i was looking for records that contained this i used 
    Like '*[IN][AN][FN]' 
 as my condition and it covers both situations.